# Is there any straight-cut formula for the sequence $n + (n-1) * 2^0 + (n-2) * 2^1 + (n-3) * 2^2 + ... + (n-(n-1)) * 2^{n-2} + (n-n) * 2^{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In GRE exam practice, I got the following question:

> Mitchell plans to work at a day camp over the summer. Each week, he will be paid according to the following schedule: at the end of the first week, he will receive \$1. At the end of each subsequent week, he will receive \$1, plus an additional amount equal to the sum of all payments he’s received in previous weeks. How much money will Mitchell be paid in total during the summer, if he works for the entire duration of the 8-week-long camp?

To do the solution, I came up with the following formula for $n$-week-long camp:

$$n + (n-1) * 2^0 + (n-2) * 2^1 + (n-3) * 2^2 + ... + (n-(n-1)) * 2^{n-2} + (n-n) * 2^{n-1}$$

But in this formula, the number of terms are dependent on $n$. So, it is going to be harder to calculate by hand for larger $n$.

So, I googled it but found no straight-cut formula where the number of terms are not dependent on n.

Could you help me? I mean, could you give me such formula or a proof that such formula does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting the question, I found the formula observing the results for several $n$s. The formula is $$2^n - 1$$

I do not know the proof as I found it just from observation. Sorry for disturbing you people.

Comment: It would be better to edit your answer to add information, rather that posting an answer

Comment: Yup... @EnamulHassan.

Comment: @enzotib Did you get this in the review queue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem follows the recurrence$$p_1=1,\\p_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k.$$

From this,

$$p_n-p_{n-1}=p_{n-1}$$ and obviously, as we have a geometric progression with $p_1=1$, $$p_n=2^{n-1}.$$

Finally, the total payment is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{k-1}=2^n-1.$$

> $$1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128=255=2^8-1.$$

Comment: @Physor: sorry, I don't do "on demand".

Answer (score 1):

$$n+\left[(n-1)*2^0+(n-2)*2^1+(n-3)*2^2+\cdots+1*2^{n-2}\right]$$
$$=n+\left[(2^0)+(2^0+2^1)+(2^0+2^1+2^2)+\cdots+(2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-2})\right]$$
$$=n+\left[(2^1-1)+(2^2-1)+(2^3-1)+\cdots+(2^{n-1}-1)\right]$$
$$=n+\left(2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1}\right)-(n-1)$$
$$=n+(2^n-2)-(n-1)$$
$$=2^n-1.$$